# How to upload file to exact location on S3 bucket using Boto

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a bucket by the path like `s3://hello/sir`. i want to upload file inside `sir` folder.I tried many things so far not able to push the file on s3. I am able to upload on `hello`  path. This is what I tried
 `s3 = boto3.resource('s3')`

`s3.Bucket('hello').upload_file('my.txt', 'sir/my.txt')`

Comment: `my.txt` is incorrect. It should be in quotes. Can you provide exact error messages you are getting or complete code?

Comment: @Marcin i corrected the typo. I am not getting any error message but when I check my s3 there are no files on the path.

Comment: Based on what you've posted there is no reason why it would not work. Without further details its difficult to speculate. You may have no permissions to upload to bucket, the bucket may not exist, the file may not exist, and many more possibilities.

Comment: @Marcin i have the access  and file exist too. when I use this `s3.Bucket(BUCKET).upload_file(file_path,'feet-reference-mask-rcnn'+file_path.split('/')[-1])` then its able to push the files inside `feet-reference-mask-rcnn` but the file also have `feet-reference-mask-rcnn` appended at its name.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I tried and worked for me:

```
import boto3


client = boto3.client('s3')
client.upload_file('/Users/data/local-file.txt', 'temp-data-user-bucket',
                   'hello/sir/sample.txt')
```

After running above code I was able to see file in `/hello/sir/` path. You can refer the below screenshot:

[image]

I am renaming the local file `local-file.txt` --> `sample.txt` while using the API but you can keep the same name this is completely optional.

You can refer the **upload_file()** API [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_file).